# Running a flash swf on server side and streaming it as video

Tags: streaming, flash

Does anyone knows if exists and what is the best tool for doing this:

1. I have a racing_car_game.swf
2. I want to run it on server side and output it via video (with red5 for example or other media server)
3. (I want to have multiple instance running on server side)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

check my name. I guess you don't have a way to do so.

You could build the functionality (in flash) to render each frame to a BitmapData-object, and then send that encoded as JPEG to a (local) service (either through URLLoader or via TCP/IP sockets) which saves them as images on file and then converts that into a movie once all frames are rendered.

EDIT: You can use a part of AS3 Core Lib ( https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib ) to convert a BitmapData into a JPEG file (in memory).

DB